# File name too long bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

i want to copy some files from ../soft to ../copu_new. The name of that tests are in ../sim/soft.txt.

I had en error : cp:cannot stat '../soft/file1.txt\file2.txt\file3.txt': File too long

Follow the code below:

```
input="../sim/soft.txt"

while read line
do
 ##to skip the first line of the file
  a=$(tail -n +1)
 ##From string to table
  for i in $a
  do 
    table_soft[$i]="$i"
  done
  for i in "${tabke_soft[@]}"
  do 
    cp ../soft/$i ../copy_new
  done
done < $input
```

The file Soft.txt is :

```
###This all tests:
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps it can't deal with the `\f` escape sequences and makes that a file named `file1.txtile2.txtile3.txt` in the directory `../soft`? Make that `/f`... instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  i don't understand. Could you detail more or rewrite the code, please?

Comment: Don't use backslahes as directory separators in `soft.txt`

Comment: Why doesn't the loop use `$line`?

Comment: `tabke_soft` is a typo, it should be `table_soft`

Comment: Something seems to be concatenating all the filenames in the file into a single element.

Comment: Do you want the first line or the last line? The comment says first line, but `tail` gets the last line.

Comment: And if you only want one line there's no need for the loop, just use `a=$(head -n 1 "$input")`

Comment: @Barmar i want to skip first line and get the others, look at my code

Comment: This code has too many problems. The job could be done simply: `while IFS= read -r file; do echo cp ../soft/"$file" ../copy_new/; done < <(tail -n +2 "$input")`

Comment: Run `bash -x yourscript` or add the command `set -x` at the top to get a log of execution so you can see exactly where things start to be surprising.

Comment: `{ read -r firstline; while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done; } <file` is itself sufficient to loop over every line but the first. Putting the `tail` _inside_ the while loop makes no sense.

Comment: BTW, as a general rule, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: `tail -n +1` will read all the lines from standard input, and you are assigning those to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely the classic bash issue where trying to run an array through a for loop gives you all the content unless you wrap it in double quotes first. Try this..

`a="$(tail -n +1)"`